# What is the difference between printing a char* with `&` and `(int*)`?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am studying a course of OOP but I'm new to C++. My instructor introduced us to character array in C++. He said that to get base address of a character array in C++ one can use either of the following:

```
char* a = "Test String";
cout << &a; // Prints base address of char array
```

or

```
char* a = "Test String";
cout << (int*)a;
```

but when I tried both for same char array I got different results. What is difference between both?

Comment: Better avoid `(int*)` in C++, but first show us a case where it differs!

Comment: Neither of those prints the base address (assuming by that the address of the first element of the array is meant)

Comment: @UnholySheep the second one does, doesn't it ?

Comment: In your question title, you promised to ask about arrays, but there is no array question, it's about addresses and pointers.

Comment: @UnholySheep So what does that actually prints?

Comment: @Wolf `"Test String"` is an array.

Comment: @Quentin but only internally, not on the code level. It's a range of const data.

Comment: @Quentin Oh right, my bad

Comment: @Wolf I'm not sure what you mean by "internally". A string literal is a constant `char` array, `char[12]` in this case.

Comment: @Quentin Well, maybe a const array, but the question does not address this. I typically try to avoid constructions like `&"hello"` and so on, so I treat string literals as *"internal"* entities, like 0 values in initializations (for example in `int i=0;` )

Comment: An instructor available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might provide better examples for you to learn about pointers and references.

Pointers are something that's well worth getting right since when you get to memory allocation, getting it wrong can be expensive.

Comment: By the way, nothing in this entire question+answers has anything to do with OOP.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes this is true that's the reason why OOP isn't one of the tag. I mentioned it so that any person who reads the question can get some background on what I am studying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the instructor. This is nonsense. The first snippet takes an address of the pointer (**not** the character array). The second snippet converts a `char` pointer to a pointer to `int` and prints the converted pointer.

The possible reason to do this is that if you try to print a pointer to `char`, compiler will choose a special overload of `operator <<` and print the string instead of a pointer. However, I'd rather convert it to `void*` than to `int*`. The reason is that converting to `void*` can be done with a safer `static_cast`.

Comment: I would add that converting to `void*` is safer, as you would not dereference it by mistake. And it should be `const char *` and `const void *` actually.

Comment: I couldn't understand your first line "The first snippet takes an address of the pointer (not the character array)." What do you mean by saying that it is not of the character array?

Comment: `char*` = pointer to character (or character array)
`char**` = pointer to pointer to character.
`&a` = char**; which is not the same as the (void*)a

Comment: Oh, now I got it &a refers to address of the pointer that represents the character array. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you did not make a mistake, your instructor provided bad example to you. Actual code should be:

```
char a[] = "Test String";
cout << &a; // Prints base address of char array
```

vs

```
char a[] = "Test String";
cout << static_cast<void *>( a ); // Prints base address of first element of char array
```

Note, assigning string literal to `char *` is deprecated in C++, it should be `const char *`

Comment: Good idea. Maybe the OP hasn't the option to *change the instructor* ;-)

Comment: So, is using static_cast<void *>(a) similar to (int*)a? since I tried both and got same result.

Comment: In this context it provides the same result, but `void *` is safer and so more proper way.

Comment: I think you reversed the order of snippets in your answer.

Comment: @SuyashMahar why do you think so?